# Ruby load error cannt load such file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, require

Testing my class source code with some require code and I keep getting the following error:

> "D:/ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
>   'require':cannot load such file -- ./xxx.rb (LoadError) from
>   D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
>   'require' from xxx.rb:1:in ''

Here is the code I'm using to test my code:

```
require "./proj6colecio.rb.txt"
print " "
guitar = Guitar.new("Stratocaster", "Fender", "Solid Body", 6, "Black")
print "Guitar Name: #{guitar.name}\n"
print "Guitar Brand: #{guitar.brand}\n"
print "Guitar Type: #{guitar.type}\n"
print "Number of Strings: #{guitar.strings}\n"
print "Guitar Color: #{guitar.color}\n"
print guitar, "\n"
```

Not really educated in ruby on rails errors yet as I'm a student still learning the basics of programming.

Thanks alot for any feedback

```
# Guitar class with instance variables @name, @brand, @type @strings @color and
# method take_strings.

class Guitar

  # initialize method is called when user invokes Guitar.new.
  def initialize(the_name, the_brand, the_type, the_strings, the_color)
    @name = the_name
    @brand = the_brand
    @type = the_type
    @strings = the_strings
    @color = the_color
  end

  # Define getters
  def name
    return @name
  end

  def brand
    return @brand
  end

  def type
    return @type
  end
  def strings
    return @strings
  end

  def color
    return @color
  end
# define setters

  def strings=(value)
    @strings = value
  end

  def to_s
    return "The Guitar is a #{name} made by #{brand}. It is a #{type} with #{strings} strings and is #{color}."
  end

  def change_color
    @color = "Blue"
  end

end

guitars = [ ]

guitars << Guitar.new("Stratocaster", "Fender", "Solid Body", 6, "Black")
guitars << Guitar.new("Les Paul", "Gibson", "Solid Body", 6, "Yellow")
guitars << Guitar.new("White Falcon", "Gretsch", "Semi-Hollow", 6, "White")

# Print all guitars
guitars.each do |g|
  print g, "\n"
end

#Change color of guitar to blue
guitars.each do |g|
  g.change_color
end

guitars.each do |g|
  print g, "\n"
end
end
```

Comment: Why `require "./proj6colecio.rb.txt"`? Maybe `require "./proj6colecio.rb"`

Comment: ya I took the .txt off just had it to read the file without text editor at school

Comment: Just a few suggestions (unrelated to the problem): Use `attr_reader :color` instead of your explicit getter. If you have getters and setters, just use `attr_accessor :color`. See [this page](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/accessors.html) for more details. Your class can be much, much shorter! You might consider using a hash for your constructor too, so you don't have to remember the order of arguments either (e.g., `def initialize(opts={}); @color = opts.fetch(:color); end`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `require_relative`:

```
require_relative "proj6colecio.rb.txt"
```

Also, you don't need a .txt file extension for a Ruby script either.

Answer (score 1):

That syntax just won't work, try `require File.join( File.dirname( __FILE__ ), '..', 'proj6colecio.rb' )`, instead.

Comment: tried that still not working here in the code i'm trying to require. editing post to show full code

Comment: You also have an extra `end`. Take off the last one.

Comment: It might help you to use a good editor, with syntax highlighting and formatting cues. I personally like RubyMine a lot.

Comment: Finally, ruby error messages are usually pretty good, once you can identify what you need from the stack trace - the reason i knew you had an extra line is this line `unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end (SyntaxError)` from the console.

Comment: thanks :D currently I'm using Jedit as my text editor ill take a look at rubymine!

Comment: nope still getting error on test code the proj6colecio.rb works fine alone

Comment: What is the error? (It runs on my machine)
`The Guitar is a Stratocaster made by Fender. It is a Solid Body with 6 strings and is Black.
The Guitar is a Les Paul made by Gibson. It is a Solid Body with 6 strings and is Yellow.
The Guitar is a White Falcon made by Gretsch. It is a Semi-Hollow with 6 strings and is White.
The Guitar is a Stratocaster made by Fender. It is a Solid Body with 6 strings and is Blue.
The Guitar is a Les Paul made by Gibson. It is a Solid Body with 6 strings and is Blue.
The Guitar is a White Falcon made by Gretsch. It is a Semi-Hollow with 6 strings and is Blue.`

Comment: the error is "D:/ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require':cannot load such file -- ./xxx.rb (LoadError) from D:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require' from xxx.rb:1:in ''               xxx.rb being the code I just at first took the name out to be anonymous

Comment: thats when I run proj6coleciotestcode.rb my teacher wants to have a code that tests all the methods and such. "proj6colecio.rb" is working fine but "proj6coleciotestcode.rb" which in the first code in the post that is not working

Comment: Just to be clear, is `proj6colecio.rb` in a directory with another directory containing the file with the require? (It should be, using this syntax). Like `/my_project/proj6colecio.rb` and `/my_project/some_dir/the_file_with_the_require.rb`...

Comment: If they are in the same dir, you can simply use `require "proj6colecio.rb.txt"`. The dot-slash makes it look like you are trying to go up a directory.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19122/discussion-between-rubynovice-and-brad-werth)

Comment: @BradWerth: You can only do `require "file-in-same-dir"` if the current directory is in your `$LOAD_PATH`, which isn't the case in 1.9. Either doing `$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.dirname(__FILE__)` before `require` or simply using `require_relative` should do the trick.

Comment: Wow thanks jmdeldin this worked you posted it eariler but when I tried I must have done it wrong thanks a lot man